# Monaco Editor Module parse failed: Unexpected token Angular 14

Tags: angular, monaco-editor, ngx-monaco-editor

My angular project stopped working after tried to use the `createDecorationsCollection` methode on the init event of the `ngx-monaco-editor` - component.
With a lot of error messages that look like these:

> ./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/actionbar/actionbar.css:6:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:0)

I already found a corresponding issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3272

But I couldn't quiet understand the solutions. Most of them could be broken down to "configure your style loaders/webpack config" correctly. But I don't even understand the problem exactly. Could somebody please explain this to me?